# Remove first word till first space from cell in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have series of strings in the database like "Et25 Silver W Mirror Cut Face Concave" i need to delete the first word and the space after it, if the string starts with an ET and have a space after any two number characters after it. Can anyone help me making such a query?

Comment: you want to update all rows for one time ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what you have tried thus far and how it isn't working?

Comment: Seems like you'd want an UPDATE statement, and to assign an expression to the column. "**`UPDATE mytable SET mycol = expr`**" with `expr` replaced with a suitable expression that operates on the existing value of mycol and returns the desired value. I'd develop and test the expression in a SELECT statement first, e.g."**`SELECT mycol, expr FROM mytable`**", and make sure the expression is "working" before I ran an UPDATE.

Comment: Yes, you can start with this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I need to write down an sql statement ofcourse and Update statment

Comment: That really isn't how this website works.  Requests for code are generally frowned upon (unless effort is demonstrated by the poster, of course.)

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad
can you see my answer below please
some one down vote it but it work 100% and i add the results to prove it's work

Answer (score 2):

The following should return what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when string regexp '^Et[0-9][0-9] '
             then substr(string, 6)
             else string
        end)
from table t;
```

EDIT:

The `update` form of the query is:

```
update table t
    set string = substr(string, 6)
    where string regexp '^Et[0-9][0-9] ';
```

Comment: I need statement to remove et*** from string using an sql statement not selecting it.

Comment: but how can i update the value in the column, because its a select statement

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad, like the following: `UPDATE table SET string = SUBSTR(string, 6) WHERE string REGEXP '^Et[0-9][0-9] ';`

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Can anyone help me making such a query?

**A:** Yes.

Seems like you'd want an UPDATE statement, and to assign an expression to the column. "**`UPDATE mytable SET mycol = expr`**" with `expr` replaced with a suitable expression that operates on the existing value of mycol and returns the desired value. I'd develop and test the expression in a SELECT statement first, e.g."**`SELECT mycol, expr FROM mytable`**", and make sure the expression is "working" before I ran an UPDATE.

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
select mid('test hello world',locate(' ','test hello world'),length('test hello world'))
```

locate : to locate the first space in the text

length : to get the length of the the text

mid : to select words between the first value ( this will be the first letter after the space ) till the second value ( that will be the last letter )

so now update query can be like

```
update a set a=mid(a,locate(' ',a),length(a)) from ...
```

here is a test code

```
create table stackoverflow (test varchar(50));
insert into stackoverflow values('a b c');
insert into stackoverflow values('d e f');
insert into stackoverflow values('g h i');
SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`;
update stackoverflow set test=mid(test,locate(' ',test),length(test));
SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`;
```

here the results

```
mysql> create table stackoverflow (test varchar(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.44 sec)

mysql> insert into stackoverflow values('a b c');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into stackoverflow values('d e f');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into stackoverflow values('g h i');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`;
+-------+
| test  |
+-------+
| a b c |
| d e f |
| g h i |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update stackoverflow set test=mid(test,locate(' ',test),length(test));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|  b c |
|  e f |
|  h i |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like
select substring(mycol, instr(mycol, ' '), len(mycol -instr(mycol, ' '))
Should word.
You can also just set the 2nd var to the max length of your string, that should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE [table] SET [field] = IF(INSTR([field],'Et'),SUBSTR([field],INSTR([field],' ')+1),[field]);
```

Very rough implementation. Gordon's RegEx based implementation could be faster.